# need to display the "Hebrew" characters

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the hexadecimal string of "000302A502B002B202B002B9000302BA02A502A702A902B9" and I need to display the "Hebrew" characters for it.
How can I convert it to Hebrew in Windows form.

Below is my tried code: (by putting in a loop until the string exists)

```
  string hexChar = hexEncodedText.Substring(0, 4);
  decodedText += (char)Int64.Parse(hexChar, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
  hexEncodedText = hexEncodedText.Substring(limit, hexEncodedText.Length - limit);
```

But this does not produce me the expected result :

Comment: What does this string mean? Is this some Base64 encoding? I can read Hebrew and it doesn't look like Hebrew :)

Comment: @IlyaKogan: It is something encoded.... but I am not sure what encoding is used ..

Comment: What is the expected result? (you have ':' but nothing after it, is something missing from the post?)

Comment: Looks like a 16-bit character set: 0003, 02a5, 02b0, 02b5, ...

Comment: @IlyaKogan - Yes, though I doubt it is Hebrew. Hebrew (unicode) characters are within range U+05D0-U+05EA. Smith - do you have some clue, how this text gets to you - i.e. can it be encrypted ?

Comment: It is rather far from my bed.  I would however be greatly surprised if a hex dump in Israel looks any different from a hex dump in the rest of the world.  The letters encode a binary nibble, not a character.  If this is really needed then a simple substitution, say A to Alef, B to Bet, etc, ought to fit the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this should work, however I've tested it and the result string is nothing. I suppose your Hebrew in Windows codepage is 1255:

```
string input = "000302A502B002B202B002B9000302BA02A502A702A902B9";
byte[] bytes = new byte[input.Length/2];
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2){
    bytes[i / 2] = byte.Parse(input.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); 
}
Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
string output = encode.GetString(bytes);
```

I think the input string is just that.